# Permission to reproduce diagram

Tags: academic-research

I'd like to get permission to reproduce the diagram on how bitcoin works at [What does a Bitcoin transaction consist of?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/what-does-a-bitcoin-transaction-consist-of) for a book on money that I'm presently writing for Routledge Publishing. How would I do that or is the image free to be used?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the diagram was produced for IEEE Spectrum. They have a [Reprints & Permissions](http://ieeespectrumreprints.magreprints.com/) page that might help to get in touch with them on this matter.