# How to take advantage of the free transaction relay policy?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, eligius, relay

I have about 0.027 BTC total, spread over 272 transactions.

Was going to send them to someone, and then the transaction fees hit me:  0.0245 BTC.  This agrees with the answer to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/how-to-calculate-transaction-size-before-sending) -- (272 txns * 180 bytes each is 49 kBytes, or 0.0005 BTC per transaction).

Then I found out about the [free transaction relay policy](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Free_transaction_relay_policy#See_Also) here, which looks like it will bring things down to a more reasonable 0.004 BTC.

I'm not understanding the mechanics of setting this up, though.  I can probably figure out how to do the following for the Eligius miner (I'm using the Bitcoin client with QT 4.8.3):

```
 Add the command-line parameter: -addnode=173.242.112.53
```

But the rest of the mechanics, I'm not sure.  Specifically:

- How do I "broadcast the transaction to it"?  Can I do this within the Bitcoin client?
- Does the person to whom I'm sending the BTC also need to add this same node?
- Do I have to specify anything else within the transaction?

My goal would be to empty my wallet of all of these tiny transactions with this reduced fee.

Edit1: Is it possible to add node 173.242.112.53 using Electrum or one of the other clients?

Answer (score 4):

By simply adding `addnode=68.168.105.168` to your [bitcoin.conf](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File) file then any transaction you send will automatically be broadcast and eventually make it into a block. No one but you has to add this node and nothing special needs to be done beyond this one configuration.

Now it may be true that the bitcoin-qt client will not actually allow you to send a transaction that is against its own rules, I'm not sure as I've never tried, but if this is the case you will need a non-standard client which is another question entirely.

Note: May 2015, 68.168.105.168 is the only Eligius relay IP I can find that's active