# Where to find UTXO Metadata API

Tags: api, utxo, raw-data, historical-trade-data

I'm looking for an API which lets me query for UTXOs on the base of specific meta data, e.g:

- When was the transaction containing the UTXO issued?
- From which address?
- etc.

I have found this question: [What is the best way to download a "recent" UTXO set snapshot?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53865/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-a-recent-utxo-set-snapshot)

But it just contains the information that it's unsafe. I'm only interested in the meta data and don't want to run a wallet on it. Therefore I'm not interested in security aspects.

Is there a war to query on the UTXO globally, without a given address? Or a way to download the whole UTXO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project: https://github.com/sr-gi/bitcoin_tools might be what you're looking for...The repo has resources to dump the leveldb database into a JSON like format for review and analysis. They also created a paper discussing the format of UTXO [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1095.pdf).

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

- [Pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin) is a highly recommended library. You can set it to query multiple blockchain API providers for safety. Here is an example to get unspent [outputs](https://github.com/priestc/moneywagon/wiki/Creating-Transactions) while creating a transaction.
- I did a similar [analysis](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51919/how-many-utxos-have-a-marginal-fee-cost-thats-higher-than-its-worth) by directly reading from .bitcoin/chainstate directory a while ago. Note: May not work with bitcoind 0.15+, as it had changes in chainstate DB format