# What is the size limit on the UTXO set, if any?

Tags: bitcoin-core, protocol, utxo-set

Other than limitations in growth of the UTXO set with regard to the block size, is there a cap either on the number of UTXOs or storage limit of the UTXO set in the Bitcoin protocol or Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such limit. Growth of the UTXO set is somewhat regulated by the fact that creating UTXOs takes up blockchain space, which may cost fees to use. But there are no size limits as such.

Comment: Cant upvote but thank you! (new account). 

I assume Murch has done calculations of "if we maximized block space to create new UTXOs for new BTC holders, how many blocks would it take for everyone on earth to have a UTXO" so Ill look for that stack exchange post next.

Comment: I don't think I've done that calculation, no. ;)

Comment: @quantumtightening: You may be interested in this answer I just wrote: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/115451/5406