# Why are transaction fees sometimes higher than what I'm transferring?

Tags: transaction-fees

Transferring from my wallet to another baffles me prior to the transaction charges. Please someone help. The charges are sometimes higher than what I am sending.

Comment: What wallet software are you using to send?  If you are sending very small amounts, then this is normal; fees are based on the number of bytes in the transaction, not the amount in bitcoins.  Bitcoin is not designed to allow people to efficiently send very small amounts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate transaction size before sending](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/how-to-calculate-transaction-size-before-sending)

Answer (score 4):

Transaction fees are not in relation to the amount of value transferred, but in relation to the amount of block space they'll take. Therefore, it is relatively cheap to send large amounts of value in Bitcoin but uneconomical to send micro-payments.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how much bitcoin you send, it matters on the size off the transaction. For example, inputs are about x bytes, outputs are y bytes, and a transaction is z bytes. If you add them all together (Let's say in one transaction, I have two inputs and one output, 2x+y+z), you will get the size of the transaction.

I use cointape.com for this. It tells me the best Satoshi/byte rate to use. Currently the network is congested, and takes about 70 sat/byte for a fast transaction. Usually it's around 20-30.