# Bitcoin transaction fee calculator

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, transaction-verification, sending

I'm new to bitcoin. Is there a website where I can type amount of BTC I want to send and type of transaction - Urgent, Normal, Economic and they give me the price in USD how much the transaction fee will be ? 
For now I just found this https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactionfees.html 
There I can see that transaction fee is 0.4$. But I don't think it could be so low.

Comment: You can find a good answer here.
[How to calculate transaction size before sending (Legacy Non-Segwit - P2PKH/P2SH)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/how-to-calculate-transaction-size-before-sending-legacy-non-segwit-p2pkh-p2sh)

Answer (score 2):

[This calculator](https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/fee-calculator/) and [this chart](https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/) are fairy useful for estimating fees. When creating a transaction with X amount of Bitcoin being spent and Y Bitcoin received, the difference (X-Y) will be the fees sent to miners. The far left column of the chart will display the amount of satoshis/byte per transaction in the mempool and the far right column will display an estimate of processing time. (Higher Satoshi/byte = more appealing to miners)

For example, [this transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/b5f804ed6fb86c033b1e31d6fea61528cc0ee3c49d35b7aff604c6f3de0f1710) is 257 bytes and was charged $3.25 in TX fees or roughly ~194 Satoshi/byte. Looking at the chart, this transaction had a much higher priority than a transaction with 10 Satoshi/byte.

A quick reminder: Fees *are not* dependent on how much Bitcoin you send, but rather how much space the transaction takes in bytes. A simple transaction between you (1 input) and another person (2 outputs, 1 change address, and 1 recipient) will have less fees than for example, a transaction with 20 outputs.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not, and you cannot make such an estimate. The fee for a transaction is not dependent on the amount being transacted. That amount is completely irrelevant for fee calculation. What matters for fee calculation is the size in bytes of the data for the transaction itself. This is dependent on your wallet and which inputs it chooses to use in the transaction.

You could have a transaction that pays $1 but has 100 inputs. That transaction would have a very high transaction fee. Conversely, you could have a transaction that pays $100,000 but has only 1 input. That transaction would have a very low fee.

Because there is no relationship between the amount being sent and the transaction fee, it is impossible to give an estimate for the transaction fee given only the amount being sent.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [bitcoinfees.net](https://bitcoinfees.net) . They have a very light and simple interface. You can easily pick a transaction fee based on confirmation time.