# How to calculate the transaction size?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees

Is it possible to calculate the transaction size from the transaction id ?

Comment: I think [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/how-to-calculate-transaction-size-before-sending-legacy-non-segwit-p2pkh-p2sh) should answer to your question more than exhaustively. If yes this can be marked as duplicate, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** That's not possible.

A transaction id is calculated from the raw transaction. More specifically the raw transaction is hashed twice with sha256: `sha256(sha256(rawtransaction))`.

That means, that the id is always 256 bits long (64 characters).
Because sha256 and hashing in general is a one-way-operation, it's not possible to calculate the size of the rawtransaction just from the transaction id.

if you need more information about a transaction, you have to fetch that from a client. In bitcoin core you can use `gettransaction` or `getrawtransaction`. (getrawtransaction only works if the transaction belongs to one of your addresses or you have `txindex` enabled in your wallet.)

Comment: TXID is `dsha256` +`endian swap` of the over-the-wire transaction serialisation.

Comment: That is part of the p2p protocol, not implementation, as this is how txids / prevouts are referenced in overthewire tx serialisations.